# Razor syntax binding attributes not working after migration from MVC 3 to MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

After migration from MVC 3 to MVC 5 construction of setting attributes in html elements stopped to work. Instead of being in the markup it is rendered on screen like raw text `class="button bold"`

```
@foreach(var part in Model){
     <div attr="@part.Id">...</div> //output: <div>...</div>
     <div class="@part.ClassName">...</div> //output: <div>...</div>
}
```

only custom attributes that are begining with `data-` are working

```
<div data-attr="@part.Id">...</div> //output: <div data-attr="7">...</div>
```

the workaround is to use `@Html.Raw` method

```
<div @Html.Raw(string.Format(@"class=""{0}""",part.ClassName))>...</div> //output: <div class="className">...</div>
```

Any ideas what happened and how to restore previous behavior?

---

Configuration

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Runtime section

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: This should work fine.Can you clean the solution , rebuild and see.Are you getting any errors or is it simply not generating ?

Comment: Done all of this many times. Simply not generating - empty space.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to capitalize Model

Comment: I agree with JB06 comment - try that first.

Comment: @JB06 sorry, Model is only an example does not have anything to do with the problem.

Comment: What do you have into runtime section of your web.config at the root of your solution? Post that here.

Comment: @CodeNotFound runtime updated.

Answer (score 3):

This will fix it.

```
<div class= "@(Model.ClassName)">...</div>
```

Comment: OK I am shocked, `magic space` solved the problem. But what is happening beneath the surface? This is not consistent with default VS code style. Someone pressing CTR + K + D will remove all spaces. Any ideas?

Comment: It is not just a space, it is the Razor symbol outside the the curly bracket. I thought you will up vote it.

Comment: Now I see that you also added bracket. Brackets does not have any influence on the behavior. Space is fixing the issue but is insufficient due to formatting problems. You now why this is fixing the problem?

Comment: Trust me, remove the space, and test it  and it will work.  It is Razor way of expressing a single line expression, @(  ),  if you have multiple line expression, you use  @{  } .

Comment: Sorry tested it in all combinations. Works even without quotation marks `<div class= @Model.ClassName >...</div>` but @() is not working without the space `<div class="@(Model.ClassName)" >...</div>`

Answer (score 1):

A picture is worth a thousand words. These three screen shots indicates without space

Action Method

[image]

View

[image]

Web Browser, Inspect Element

[image]

Comment: OK  I clearly see that this is working for you. I slightly updated my example  because it is rendering in the foreach loop (I think this make no difference). Also I see that the `class` part is rendered on the screen.

Comment: By that I mean that on the page there is a raw text `class="button bold"` not in the markup.

Comment: I am glad you got it working. I can only work with the information I see here, I do not have access to your entire code and would not know anything except the information I here.

Comment: Hmmm you misunderstood me. It is still not working for me, I believe that it works for you but for me it is some kind of upgrade problem :)